# Capturar nome de arquivos em diretorio

Tags: java, arquivo

O método a seguir pega o nome dos arquivos de um determinado diretório e os exibe na tela, o problema é que o `.listfiles()` retorna o numero de bytes e não a quantidade de arquivos,  apesar de mostrar o nome dos arquivos acabo tendo um erro de *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* já que estou tentando acessar valores que não existem. Como posso pegar o nome dos arquivos do diretório sem erros?

```
   public static void getImgs(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    File[] arquivos = file.listFiles();

    for (int i=0; i<file.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(arquivos[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O modo mais fácil de não cair nessa exception é utilizar um foreach. Exemplo:

```
public static void getImgs(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    File[] arquivos = file.listFiles();

    for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
        System.out.println(arquivo);
    }
}
```

Em `for (File arquivo : arquivos)` a própria JVM é responsável por iterar pelos arquivos da sua lista, e ela garante que você nunca terá um `arquivo` que não existe no array (mas a variável em si depende da sua lista, então em outros casos `arquivo` poderia conter o valor `null`, por exemplo).

Answer (score 4):

Sempre que possível prefira a nova API do Java 8 que usa a classe [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).

Por exemplo, você pode listar os arquivos de um diretório assim:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/tmp"), 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
        .forEach(path -> System.out.printf("%s%n", path.toAbsolutePath().toString()));
```

O primeiro parâmetro é o diretório em si, que é um `Path` construído usando o método `Paths.get()`. Note que este método pode receber uma quantidade arbitrária de parâmetros, então você não precisa mais se preocupar com barras, porque você sempre pode especificar cada componente do caminho em um parâmetro separado.

O segundo argumento define se a rotina vai ler subdiretórios. Neste caso, `1` (um) significa que eu estou listando apenas o diretório atual. Para ler todos os subdiretórios, use `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

O terceiro parâmetro recebe `FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS` para indicar ao Java que ele deve considerar os atalhos como usados no linux/unix. Considero importante sempre usar esse parâmetro.

O método `walk` retorna um `Stream`, que é a forma funcional do Java 8 de percorrer uma sequência de elementos. O `forEach` permite executar um comando para cada elemento do `Stream`, que no caso, imprime o caminho absoluto dentro da expressão lambda.

Se você quiser, por exemplo, filtrar os tipos de arquivo, pode fazer assim:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/tmp"), 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
        .filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".log"))
        .forEach(path -> System.out.printf("%s%n", path.toAbsolutePath().toString()));
```

A diferença aqui é o `filter` que deixa no `Stream` todos os caminhos que terminam com `.log`. A sintaxe pode não ser fácil no começo, mas o que o código faz é bastante óbvio.

Finalmente, existe um atalho para já filtrar os arquivos na hora de listar, o método `Files.find`. Exemplo:

```
Files.find(Paths.get("/tmp"), 1,
        (path, attributes) -> attributes.isRegularFile() && path.toString().endsWith(".log"),
        FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS
).forEach(path -> System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath()));
```

Este método é mais eficiente e permite facilmente acessar os atributos do arquivo. No caso, eu estou verificando se é um arquivo normal e não um diretório ou símbolo usando `attributes.isRegularFile()`.

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra abordagem é usar a biblioteca [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). Ela tem vários métodos utilitários.

Por exemplo o método [`listFiles(java.io.File, java.lang.String[], boolean)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean)). Onde você define um diretório raiz, um array de String com as extensões e um booleano indicando se a busca deve ser recursiva (em subdiretórios). Ao final você pode manipular a `Collection` resultante.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar [**`DirectoryStream<T>`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) onde o tipo genérico é uma interface [**`Path`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html):

```
// C:\Users\Fulano\Desktop
Path diretorio = Paths.get("C:", "Users", "Fulano", "Desktop");

try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(diretorio){
  for(Path path : stream)
     System.out.println(path.getFileName());
}
```

---

Se precisar listar arquivos com extensões especificas, use o segundo parâmetro do método [**`Files#newDirectoryStream()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String%29) passando uma string com o modelo das extensões filtradas:

```
// Listando todos os arquivos com extensão ".java"
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(diretorio, "*.java"){
  for(Path path : stream)
     System.out.println(path.getFileName());
}
```

```
// Listando arquivos com extensão .jpg, .gif e .png     
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(diretorio, "*.{jpg,gif,png}"){
  for(Path path : stream)
     System.out.println(path.getFileName());
}
```

Caso queira ir além e obter também os arquivos que estiverem em pastas nesse mesmo diretório, encontrei [nessa resposta <sup><sup><sup>[en]</sup></sup></sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20987341/4056678) uma solução usando recursividade.

Answer (score -1):

Segue um modo simples que me ajudou e pode ajudar a você também:

Componentes utilizados:

1. 01 JTextField com o nome "txtCaminho";
2. 01 JButton com o nome "btnBusca";

---

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.showOpenDialog(this);

try {

  File arquivo = fc.getSelectedFile();
  String caminho = arquivo.getAbsolutePath();
  caminho = caminho.replace('\\', '/');

  // aqui eu mostro numa JTextField o caminho absoluto
  txtLocal.setText(caminho);                 

  String nomeArq = new File(caminho).getName();
  System.out.println(nomeArq);

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Deu tudo errado...);
}
```

Comment: Seria interessante remover os componentes de swing, pois isso é irrelevante para a solução do problema.

Comment: Sim, com certeza! Na realidade postei o trecho do código o qual estou utilizando aqui. Mas valeu o alerta!